# Excel MATCH with multiple criteria (not exact match)

Tags: excel

I have been tinkering with various Excel functions (MATCH/INDEX, VLOOKUP, SUMPRODUCT, AGGREGATE, etc.) to deliver the result I need, but without success.  So I'm hoping someone can tell me what the best way to do this is.

From my sample data below I need a formula that will return the row number accurately when I provide the exact code (exact match with column A) along with a date that falls between the dates listed in column B.  I started with a formula that *does* work when both items match exactly -- i.e.,

```
=MATCH(1,(("B"=A:A)*(2005=B:B)),0)
```

will return row 6, which is correct.  But I cannot figure out how to tweak that so it works when I search for Code=B and Year=2007.  In this case I want it to return row 6 -- where Code=B and the year is the closest / next lower value.  My closest attempt (which does not work) is:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(MATCH(1,(A:A="B")*(B:B<=2007),0))
```

Any help appreciated!

[image: Sample Data]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions -- I will experiment with all of these and report back.  Also I should have mentioned initially ... I'm using Excel 365 (but need the solution to work on earlier Excel versions, also)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use AGGREGATE:

```
=AGGREGATE(14,7,ROW($A$2:$A$7)/((D1=$A$2:$A$7)*($B$2:$B$7<=D2)),1)
```

[image]

Comment: This works!  This is similar to what I had in mind ... I had tried the Aggregate approach but could not get it to work.  I was not including the ROW($A:$A)/ part of your formula.  What is that doing?  (It works but now I would like to understand why!)

Comment: That is what is returned, we want the row number.  The denominator causes there to e divide by 0 errors when either is false.  Those are ignored and the max row number is returned where both are true.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try using `LOOKUP()` Function instead of `MATCH()`

[image]

• Formula used in cell `E5`

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/((E2=$A$2:$A$7)*($B$2:$B$7<=E3)),ROW($B$2:$B$7))
```

Answer (score 0):

### Updated

If you have Excel 2019 or better, this should work.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(  INDEX( SORT(FILTER(ABS(B:B-E2)&REPT("",5)&ROW(B:B),A:A=E1),1,1),1,1),5),"","")+0
```

Sorry, first answer got got distracted:

[image]

Comment: I did it for `A` Sorry.